# How to integrate Stripe with Apple iOS App store purchases (subscriptions)?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

What workflow have others use to cleanly integrate subscriptions across Stripe and Apple Purchases (subscriptions), and eventually Android.

I have a web app that uses Stripe Subscriptions (monthly and annual plans to pay for the app) and am launching an iOS App which requires in-app (Guideline 3.1.1 by apple) purchases.  How do you keep the 2 in sync? knowing that all the webhook and subscription data/database connection is connected to Stripe (i.e. Stripe is the source of truth)

Option 1) Create a Stripe Customer & Subscription with a 100% off coupon so subscription stays live and then use Apple webhooks to cancel or change the status of the stripe data. (So the app/database is un-aware of Apple/Android)

Option 2) Create a parallel functionality from Apple with apple webhooks to app/database around subscriptions, so it's independent from Stripe.

Option 3) ???

Thanks!

Comment: Stripe supports using Apple/Google pay with its subscription integrations, so you may not need to use the native SDKs (See the "Walllets" section of this doc) https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options?paymentintents-or-orders=paymentintents#additional-api-vouchers

Comment: @Pompey this won't be allowed due to the 3.1.1 clause of Apple IAP which requires in app purchases to go through them - so they can take their cut.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a bit late to the party, however, I do not think you can use Stripe as the source of truth in this case.

Instead, **your database would be the source of truth** because Apple needs to handle subscriptions through their in-app purchases.

So, a user could subscribe on Android (for example) and your database will flag them as a subbed user.  Then if they then log-in on an Apple device, they'd get access to all the proper unlocked content because they are a "subbed user" as far as your database is concerned, regardless of Apple or Stripe.

Visa-versa, it works the same: If they subbed through Apple's in-app purchases, it would work the same way, after completing the payment, you'd flag the user on your database as a subbed user and open up the content to them regardless of where they sub.

Doing this is necessary for Apple to allow sub-locked content in your app when they are approving your app.  They just want *the option for the user to sub through the in-app with apple*, but the user could still not give apple it's cut by subbing online, for example, then logging in again on their apple device, lol.

**The Logistics**

In this case, you have to manage Stripe sub options AND Apple sub options at the same time without any way to sync them smoothly.  This may be the actual problem you are worried about.  As in, for ex., when you change a sub price or description on Stirpe, you will have to also open Apple Store Connect and alter the price or description in the In-App Purchases for that same subscription to reflect the change.

If this is the actual logistical issue you are wondering about, then I am also wondering about it and would love to know if you've come up with any useful solutions.